# deleting escape characters python

Tags: python

```
        temp = str(read_temp())
        ### temp is 29.12
        temp = binascii.hexlify(temp)
        ### now temp is 32392e3132
        n = 2
        ta = [temp[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(temp), n)]
        ### now ta[0]=32 ta[1]=39 ta[2]=2e ta[3]=31 ta[4]=32 
        print(type(ta[0]))
        data_send = r'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x'+ta[0]+r'\x'+ta[1]+r'\x'+ta[2]+r'\x'+ta[3]+r'\x'+ta[4]
        data_send = literal_eval("'%s'" %data_send) # that can be delete
        yield Task(self.send, data_send)
```

Hi,  `python version=2.7.1.6`

I read the temperature. Example of temperature is 29.22 *C. I want to add this value of temperature to data_send like ascii code. Then i will send the data on tornado web server on iec104 protocol.
when i print the data the result is `'\x00\x00\x00\x0028.87'`. I want to change this data like that`'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x32\x38\x2e\x38\x37'`. But the result goes on like that: `\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x32\\x38\\x2e\\x38\\x37`

I want to delete this extra escaping character `\`

Please help me

Comment: The escape \ is not a separate character. It is syntax of a single character composed of \ and the following. For example, \x00 is a single character (the NUL) and so is \x37 (the digit 7).

Comment: I read `literal_eval` to deleting escaping character. But that doesnt work. Just extra information. We can delete that

Comment: `'\x00\x00\x00\x0028.87'` is equivalent to `'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x32\x38\x2e\x38\x37'`, it's just a matter of "styling". Why do you insist on the latter format?

Comment: I have to send the data from client to server on iec104 protocol. and that protocol allows the format of data like that `'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x32\x38\x2e\x38\x37'`. Because of hex values. So I have to write data like that

Comment: I think you are confusing how Python prints (or 'styles') the string of bytes when printed and what its "actual" value is. As @deceze says, if a `bytes` object prints as `b'\x00\x00\x00\x0028.87'`, it is exactly what you need, it just prints like that because `28.87` are all printable characters, while `\x00` is not.

Comment: It converts data to `0000000032382e3837` if ı convert this data to string that goes `29.97`

Comment: I love @deceze. yeapp that is real problem. I couldnt solve that problem

Comment: Why are you doing all these convoluted contortions? `r'\x00\x00\x00\x00' + str(read_temp()).encode('ascii')`, done. Probably it can be even more simplified, depending on what `read_temp` returns exactly.

Comment: I think you need to clear up conceptually whether you want *bytes* or *characters*, and then consider what exactly you're looking at and how Python presents you something. [This article](http://kunststube.net/encoding) may be a good first step to understanding the difference between bytes and characters. Then you need to clearly keep in mind whether you want a `NUL` byte, which in Python is represented as `'\x00'`, or the string "backslash, ex zero zero", which is `r'\x00'` *or* `'\\x00'`. Then consider the same for your `temp` characters.

Comment: ı know that but ı couldnt convert bit to string or string to bit

Comment: heeeeeeeeeey ı solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `r`-prefixed strings (raw strings). Within raw strings, any backslashes are interpreted literally, not as an escape character. If you want a string in which each character has the actual hex value you're encoding, like `'\x00'` for `0`, remove the `r` prefix from the string.

Then, when printing the string, use the `repr` function to reverse the encoding (i.e. to see the escape sequences used):

```py
>>> s = b"\x61\x00\x12"
>>> print(repr(s))
b'a\x00\x12'
```

Note that any hex value that corresponds to a printable character (like `x61` above) will be shown as the actual character (`a` in this case), instead of the escape sequence.

The string will contain the actual values encoded with a hex escape sequence:

```py
>>> print(*s)
97 0 18
```

---

If you just want a string of literal escape sequences, regardless of whether the character is printable or not, you'll have to do it manually.

Given a list of numbers you want to encode as hex sequences,

```py
nums = [97, 0, 18]
```

you can do

```py
escaped = ''.join(r'\x{:02x}'.format(num) for num in nums)
```

(in the format specification, `0` is the fill character, `2` is the width, and `x` indicates hexadecimal). Now, if you print `escaped`, you will see a string of escape sequences:

```py
>>> print(escaped)
\x61\x00\x12
```

Comment: hey thanks for helping. That works on python3 but ı have to use python2 for this protocol :( @anakhand

Comment: @MücahidDoğan You should be able to replace `rf'\x{num:02x}'` with `r'\x{:02x}'.format(num)` and it should work in Python 2 too.

Comment: thanks for advice but in nums i am using string, not int bro. `nums=["23","0","12", "."]`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to send a temperature as plain text characters after four null characters, this will work:

```
temp = str(read_temp())
data_send = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00' + temp.encode('ascii')
yield Task(self.send, data_send)
```

Also, just:

```
print(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00' + '28.87'.encode('ascii'))
```

Result:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x0028.87'
```

Which is exactly what you need, i.e. a string of bytes, four `chr(0)` followed by a `chr(0x32)`, `chr(0x38)`, `chr(0x2e)`, `chr(0x38)` and `chr(0x37)`.

Unless of course the service somehow expects a Python string representation of the data, which would be more than a bit odd, but not impossible.

Comment: That shows the data like that `'\x00\x00\x00\x0032392e3132'` But that doesnt work. I want the data like that `'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x32\x39\x2e\x31\x32'`. Now I am trying all characters by myself and I will comment the result. It must be work

Comment: There was a typo in there, someone already fixed it (wrong quotes)

Comment: wheeeere I couldn't find that man. I will be grateful if you help me @grismar

Comment: Have you tried the example as it currently stands? (note that it had ` quotes previously, where it now has ' quotes)